# Button not display its value inside "eco" tag

Tags: php, html, pdo

[image]

```
while(($res =  $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) && ($c<$row)) {
    $c=$c+1;
    echo"<tr style='color:#00284d;font-size:15px;';>
                            <td style='background-color:#00284d;color:white;width:30px;'>{$c}</td>
                            <td>{$res['user_id']}</td>
                            <td>{$res['user_name']}</td>
                            <td>{$res['user_type']}</td>
                            <td><button type='button' name='edit' id='edit' **value='".$res['user_id']."'** class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='width:72px;'/></td>
                            <td><button type='button' name='delete' id='delete' value='".$res['user_id']."'  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='asd();' style='width:72px;'/></td>
    // not display button inside value, always display 1 (display mean actually i checked what is the its value using javascript) 
    </tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this piece of code same as the rest.

This is the code to change

```
<td><button type='button' name='edit' id='edit' **value='".$res['user_id']."'** class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='width:72px;'/></td>
<td><button type='button' name='delete' id='delete' value='".$res['user_id']."'  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='asd();' style='width:72px;'/></td>
```

Like this

```
<td><button type='button' name='edit' id='edit' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='width:72px;' value='{$res['user_id']}'>{$res['user_id']}</button> </td>
<td><button type='button' name='delete' id='delete' value='{$res['user_id']}'  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='asd();' style='width:72px;' value='{$res['user_id']}'>{$res['user_id']}</button></td>
```

Comment: thanks, button text is displayed, but how i get each button value(displayed text) when button click.(button has same name)(becouse i wont access if(isset($_POST[buttonname]) method)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the text between the `<button></button>` tag

```
<button type='button' name='edit' id='edit' **value='".$res['user_id']."'** class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='width:72px;'>EDIT</button>

<button type='button' name='delete' id='delete' value='".$res['user_id']."'  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='asd();' style='width:72px;'>
    DELETE
</button>
```